# xlst to add elements from header node into other nodes (not children of header)

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

This is an extension of the question at:

[How to import XML with layers of nested nodes (parent/child/child relationships) into Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193600/how-to-import-xml-with-layers-of-nested-nodes-parent-child-child-relationships)

I'm trying to insert the 2 elements PeriodStartDate and PeriodEndDate into the Cuesheet node of this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CueSheets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
<Header>
    <ReportType>C</ReportType>
    <ReportPeriodStartDate>20110101</ReportPeriodStartDate>
    <ReportPeriodEndDate>20150814</ReportPeriodEndDate>
</Header>
<CueSheet>
    <NewOrUpdate>N</NewOrUpdate>
    <EbiquityId>7234709</EbiquityId>
    <EbiquityFilename>7234709_1.mpg</EbiquityFilename>
    <AdTitle>2015- Available Now At The Warehouse.</AdTitle>
    <AdDescription>Artists listed. Retailers listed.</AdDescription>
    <AdDuration>00:00:15</AdDuration>
    <FirstTransmissionDate>20150212</FirstTransmissionDate>
    <FirstTransmissionStation>FOUR</FirstTransmissionStation>
    <Brand>Summer Mix Tape</Brand>
    <Product>cd release</Product>
        <Cue>
            <TrackSequenceNumber>3</TrackSequenceNumber>
            <TrackTitle>Geronimo</TrackTitle>
            <Artists>
            <Artist>Sheppard</Artist>
            </Artists>
            <Composers>
                <Composer>George Sheppard</Composer>
                <Composer>Amy Sheppard ,Jay Bovino</Composer>
            </Composers>
            <ProductionMusic>N</ProductionMusic>
            <RecordLabels>
                <RecordLabel>UMI Decca Records</RecordLabel>
            </RecordLabels>
            <ISRCs>
                <ISRC>AU-IYA-14-00002</ISRC>
            </ISRCs>
            <ARID>204313468</ARID>
            <TimeIn>00:00:09</TimeIn>
            <TimeOut>00:00:15</TimeOut>
            <Duration>00:00:06</Duration>
        </Cue>
    <Complete>Y</Complete>
</CueSheet>
</CueSheets>
```

Here is the xslt as it stands (inserting EbiquityId from Cuesheets into Cue node is working, so I know I'm on the right track thanks to @michael.kor257 and @Parfait):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="periodStart" select="/Header/ReportPeriodStartDate"/>
<xsl:variable name="periodEnd" select="/Header/ReportPeriodEndDate"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cuesheet">
    <xsl:copy>    
        <ReportPeriodStartDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="$periodStart"/>
        </ReportPeriodStartDate>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cuesheet">
    <xsl:copy>    
        <ReportPeriodEndDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="$periodEnd"/>
        </ReportPeriodEndDate>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cue|Artists|Composers|RecordLabels|ISRCs">
    <xsl:copy>    
        <EbiquityId>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::CueSheet/EbiquityId"/>
        </EbiquityId>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have templates matching `Cuesheet`, which is not allowed. XSLT processors will either signal an error, or choose only the last template, when trying to match a node. Also note, XSLT is case-sensitive. The template matches `Cuesheet`, but the element in your XML is `CueSheet`

Additionally, the definition of `periodStart` and `periodEnd` is not correct as it is looking for a root element of `Header`, but your root element is `CueSheets`, so it should look like this

```
<xsl:variable name="periodStart" select="/CueSheets /Header/ReportPeriodStartDate"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="periodStart" select="/CueSheets/Header/ReportPeriodStartDate"/>
<xsl:variable name="periodEnd" select="/CueSheets/Header/ReportPeriodEndDate"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CueSheet">
    <xsl:copy>    
        <ReportPeriodStartDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="$periodStart"/>
        </ReportPeriodStartDate>
        <ReportPeriodEndDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="$periodEnd"/>
        </ReportPeriodEndDate>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cue|Artists|Composers|RecordLabels|ISRCs">
    <xsl:copy>    
        <EbiquityId>
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::CueSheet/EbiquityId"/>
        </EbiquityId>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim, could I also have used `select="ancestor::Header/ReportPeriodStartDate"` to set the variables?

Comment: `select="ancestor::Header/ReportPeriodStartDate"`would not work because the context will be the document node, and `Header` is not an ancestor of that. This would work though...  `select="/Header/ReportPeriodStartDate"`

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility to solve this. Then put the Report-Node-Names into the variables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[local-name()!='Header']"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="CueSheet">
  <xsl:element name="CueSheet">
   <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
   <xsl:copy-of select="../Header/ReportPeriodStartDate" />
   <xsl:copy-of select="../Header/ReportPeriodEndDate" />
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```