# How to parse NVD CVE XML and import to Database

Tags: xml, parsing

I want to parse large XML file and storage they into database(mysql)
XML like this:
File XML ~ 200MB
How can I do to parse this XML file?
How to get child element like . Its has 2 part 'vuln' and 'vulnerable-configuration'
Thanks!

```
<entry id="CVE-2015-0002">
    <vuln:vulnerable-configuration id="http://www.nist.gov/">
      <cpe-lang:logical-test operator="OR" negate="false">
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_7:-:sp1"/>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2008:r2:sp1"/>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_8:-"/>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_8.1:-"/>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2012:-:gold"/>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2012:r2::~~~x64~~"/>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_rt:-:gold"/>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_rt_8.1:-"/>
      </cpe-lang:logical-test>
    </vuln:vulnerable-configuration>
    <vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2012:-:gold</vuln:product>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_rt:-:gold</vuln:product>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_7:-:sp1</vuln:product>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_rt_8.1:-</vuln:product>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2012:r2::~~~x64~~</vuln:product>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_8:-</vuln:product>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_8.1:-</vuln:product>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2008:r2:sp1</vuln:product>
    </vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
    <vuln:cve-id>CVE-2015-0002</vuln:cve-id>
    <vuln:published-datetime>2015-01-13T17:59:01.253-05:00</vuln:published-datetime>
    <vuln:last-modified-datetime>2015-01-14T16:51:14.253-05:00</vuln:last-modified-datetime>
    <vuln:cvss>
      <cvss:base_metrics>
        <cvss:score>7.2</cvss:score>
        <cvss:access-vector>LOCAL</cvss:access-vector>
        <cvss:access-complexity>LOW</cvss:access-complexity>
        <cvss:authentication>NONE</cvss:authentication>
        <cvss:confidentiality-impact>COMPLETE</cvss:confidentiality-impact>
        <cvss:integrity-impact>COMPLETE</cvss:integrity-impact>
        <cvss:availability-impact>COMPLETE</cvss:availability-impact>
        <cvss:source>http://nvd.nist.gov</cvss:source>
        <cvss:generated-on-datetime>2015-01-14T16:20:33.273-05:00</cvss:generated-on-datetime>
      </cvss:base_metrics>
    </vuln:cvss>
    <vuln:cwe id="CWE-264"/>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="VENDOR_ADVISORY">
      <vuln:source>MS</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://technet.microsoft.com/security/bulletin/MS15-001" xml:lang="en">MS15-001</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="UNKNOWN">
      <vuln:source>MISC</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="https://code.google.com/p/google-security-research/issues/detail?id=118" xml:lang="en">https://code.google.com/p/google-security-research/issues/detail?id=118</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="UNKNOWN">
      <vuln:source>MISC</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-discloses-unpatched-windows-vulnerability/" xml:lang="en">http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-discloses-unpatched-windows-vulnerability/</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="UNKNOWN">
      <vuln:source>MISC</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://twitter.com/sambowne/statuses/550384131683520512" xml:lang="en">http://twitter.com/sambowne/statuses/550384131683520512</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:summary>The AhcVerifyAdminContext function in ahcache.sys in the Application Compatibility component in Microsoft Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 Gold and R2, and Windows RT Gold and 8.1 does not verify that an impersonation token is associated with an administrative account, which allows local users to gain privileges by running AppCompatCache.exe with a crafted DLL file, aka MSRC ID 20544 or "Microsoft Application Compatibility Infrastructure Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability."</vuln:summary>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer.

First of all look at this link to answer most of your question,
[How to import XML with nested nodes (parent/child relationships) into Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029303/how-to-import-xml-with-nested-nodes-parent-child-relationships-into-access)

Import XML to Access, and use a file to transform the XML so that each sub table get the key *vuln:cve-id* to link back to the main table *entry*

The below code works for some of the sub tables but not all, If anyone can point out why it does not work for all sub tables please do so.
However it does give you the main table with *vuln:cve-id vuln:published-datetime vuln:last-modified-datetime vuln:summary* plus the *cvss:base_metrics cvss:score cvss:access-vector cvss:access-complexity cvss:source  cvss:generated-on-datetime*.

Put the below code in a file called transform.xslt and use it when importing into access. you need to add the appropriate XSL headders, I could not add them in this post as "you need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links" :-(

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </dataroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cpe-lang:logical-test">
    <cpe-lang:logical-test>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </cpe-lang:logical-test>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:vulnerable-configuration">
    <vuln:vulnerable-configuration>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:vulnerable-configuration>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:vulnerable-software-list">
    <vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cvss:base_metrics">
    <cvss:base_metrics>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </cvss:base_metrics>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:references">
    <vuln:references>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:references>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:scanner">
    <vuln:scanner>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:scanner>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old, but I briefly worked on something similar to your question. It's some pretty ugly code (did it in a couple hours), but I think it does most of what you ask for except for exporting to a database. It uses giant XML files (CVEs), parses them for specific key/value pairs, and compares them to a network scan.

https://github.com/bhealy/netScan

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(XMLfile)
root = tree.getroot()
stuffYouCareAbout = root[0][1][2][3].text
```

I was able to parse the XML file using etree which made it a lot easier to find specific items. Obviously the sample is looking at a very specific index, but it should be a good starting point (if this post isn't too late!)