# Import NVD data feed to MS access database

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

With reference to existing question [How to parse NVD CVE XML and import to Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792373/how-to-parse-nvd-cve-xml-and-import-to-database/38564418#38564418) that I managed to give a partial answer to, I need to extend that question (and I could not comment on the existing question)

I need to import the XML data from https://nvd.nist.gov/download.cfm to MS Access.

[edit]

the structure in the database I am looking to create is as follows:

MainTable(entry)

- Element(vuln:cve-id)
- Element(vuln:vulnerable-configuration)
- Element(vuln:summary)
- Element(vuln:published-datetime)
- Element(vuln:last-modified-datetime)
- Element(cvss:score)
- Element(cvss:access-vector)
- Element(cvss:access-complexity)
- Element(cvss:source)
- Element(cvss:generated-on-datetime)
- Atribute(entry id)
- Atribute(vuln:assessment_check system)
- Atribute(vuln:assessment_check href)
- Atribute(vuln:assessment_check name)
- Atribute(vuln:cwe id) Atribute(vuln:vulnerable-configuration id)
- Atribute(cpe-lang:logical-test operator)
- Atribute(cpe-lang:logical-test negate)

ChildTable(fact-ref)

- Element(vuln:cve-id) [from entry table]
- Atribute(cpe-lang:fact-ref name)

ChildTable(Product)

- Element(vuln:cve-id) [from entry table]
- Element(vuln:product)

ChildTable(References)

- Element(vuln:cve-id) [from entry table]
- Element(vuln:source)
- Element(vuln:reference)
- Atribute(vuln:references xml:lang)
- Atribute(vuln:references reference_type)

ChildTable(scanner)

- Element(vuln:cve-id) [from entry table]
- Atribute(vuln:definition system)
- Atribute(vuln:definition href)
- Atribute(vuln:definition name)

however, if e.g. the records in segment *cvss:base_metrics* end up in separate table that is not a big problem.

The following XML is an abridged but still valid set of XML that contains 2 *entry* records, and no more than 3 child records per child table.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<nvd xmlns:scap-core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2" xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1" xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0" xmlns:cpe-lang="http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0" nvd_xml_version="2.0" pub_date="2016-06-17T05:29:06" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/patch_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/nvd-cve-feed_2.0.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/scap-core_0.1.xsd">
  <entry id="CVE-2003-0001">
    <vuln:vulnerable-configuration id="http://www.nist.gov/">
      <cpe-lang:logical-test operator="OR" negate="false">
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:4.2"/>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_2000_terminal_services::sp2"/>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/o:netbsd:netbsd:1.5"/>
      </cpe-lang:logical-test>
    </vuln:vulnerable-configuration>
    <vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:freebsd:freebsd:4.7</vuln:product>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.4.10</vuln:product>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_2000::sp2:datacenter_server</vuln:product>
    </vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
    <vuln:cve-id>CVE-2003-0001</vuln:cve-id>
    <vuln:published-datetime>2003-01-17T00:00:00.000-05:00</vuln:published-datetime>
    <vuln:last-modified-datetime>2016-06-16T21:59:02.180-04:00</vuln:last-modified-datetime>
    <vuln:cvss>
      <cvss:base_metrics>
        <cvss:score>5.0</cvss:score>
        <cvss:access-vector>NETWORK</cvss:access-vector>
        <cvss:access-complexity>LOW</cvss:access-complexity>
        <cvss:source>http://nvd.nist.gov</cvss:source>
        <cvss:generated-on-datetime>2016-06-13T11:15:01.477-04:00</cvss:generated-on-datetime>
      </cvss:base_metrics>
    </vuln:cvss>
    <vuln:assessment_check system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5" href="http://oval.mitre.org/repository/data/getDef?id=oval:org.mitre.oval:def:2665" name="oval:org.mitre.oval:def:2665"/>
    <vuln:cwe id="CWE-200"/>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="VENDOR_ADVISORY">
      <vuln:source>CERT-VN</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/412115" xml:lang="en">VU#412115</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="UNKNOWN">
      <vuln:source>BUGTRAQ</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/307564/30/26270/threaded" xml:lang="en">20030117 Re: More information regarding Etherleak</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="UNKNOWN">
      <vuln:source>BUGTRAQ</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/archive/1/305335/30/26420/threaded" xml:lang="en">20030106 Etherleak: Ethernet frame padding information leakage (A010603-1)</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:scanner>
      <vuln:definition system="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-definitions-5" href="http://oval.mitre.org/repository/data/DownloadDefinition?id=oval:org.mitre.oval:def:2665" name="oval:org.mitre.oval:def:2665"/>
    </vuln:scanner>
    <vuln:summary>Multiple ethernet Network Interface Card (NIC) device drivers do not pad frames with null bytes, which allows remote attackers to obtain information from previous packets or kernel memory by using malformed packets, as demonstrated by Etherleak.</vuln:summary>
  </entry>
  <entry id="CVE-2003-0002">
    <vuln:vulnerable-configuration id="http://nvd.nist.gov/">
      <cpe-lang:logical-test operator="OR" negate="false">
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/a:microsoft:content_management_server:2001"/>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref name="cpe:/a:microsoft:content_management_server:2001:sp1"/>
      </cpe-lang:logical-test>
    </vuln:vulnerable-configuration>
    <vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/a:microsoft:content_management_server:2001</vuln:product>
      <vuln:product>cpe:/a:microsoft:content_management_server:2001:sp1</vuln:product>
    </vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
    <vuln:cve-id>CVE-2003-0002</vuln:cve-id>
    <vuln:published-datetime>2003-02-07T00:00:00.000-05:00</vuln:published-datetime>
    <vuln:last-modified-datetime>2008-09-10T20:05:22.087-04:00</vuln:last-modified-datetime>
    <vuln:cvss>
      <cvss:base_metrics>
        <cvss:score>6.8</cvss:score>
        <cvss:access-vector approximated="true">NETWORK</cvss:access-vector>
        <cvss:access-complexity approximated="true">MEDIUM</cvss:access-complexity>
        <cvss:authentication approximated="true">NONE</cvss:authentication>
        <cvss:generated-on-datetime>2004-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00</cvss:generated-on-datetime>
      </cvss:base_metrics>
    </vuln:cvss>
    <vuln:security-protection>ALLOWS_OTHER_ACCESS</vuln:security-protection>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="VENDOR_ADVISORY">
      <vuln:source>MS</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms03-002.asp" xml:lang="en">MS03-002</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:references xml:lang="en" reference_type="VENDOR_ADVISORY">
      <vuln:source>XF</vuln:source>
      <vuln:reference href="http://www.iss.net/security_center/static/10318.php" xml:lang="en">mcms-manuallogin-reasontxt-xss (10318)</vuln:reference>
    </vuln:references>
    <vuln:summary>Cross-site scripting vulnerability (XSS) in ManualLogin.asp script for Microsoft Content Management Server (MCMS) 2001 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary script via the REASONTXT parameter.</vuln:summary>
  </entry>
</nvd>
```

[end edit]

I am able to import all tables, and I am able to add the link *vuln:cve-id* as a key to all child tables I import except the child table *vuln:vulnerable-configuration*.

I have two main problems:

1. I can not import Attributes only Elements
2. When a child table has more than one record relating to the main table entry only the last record in the XML will be imported to MS Access. [edit, this is now solved, see below, end edit]

first issue 1) I have tried to use the following code to import attributes,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:scap-core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2" xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1" xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0" xmlns:cpe-lang="http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/patch_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/nvd-cve-feed_2.0.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/scap-core_0.1.xsd" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it works as long as I do not use name spaces, but as soon as I use XMLNS to define a name space in the XSLT file MS Access throws me an error that "Prefixes 'xml' and 'xmlns' are reserved for use by XML." However if I use the following XSLT and do not attempt to do any conversion of Attribute to Element MS Access is OK using the same XMLNS commands.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:scap-core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2" xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1" xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0" xmlns:cpe-lang="http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/patch_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/nvd-cve-feed_2.0.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/scap-core_0.1.xsd" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </dataroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cpe-lang:logical-test">
    <cpe-lang:logical-test>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </cpe-lang:logical-test>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:vulnerable-configuration">
    <vuln:vulnerable-configuration>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:vulnerable-configuration>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:vulnerable-software-list">
    <vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cvss:base_metrics">
    <cvss:base_metrics>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </cvss:base_metrics>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:references">
    <vuln:references>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:references>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:scanner">
    <vuln:scanner>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:scanner>
</xsl:template>
```

Issue 2) When a child table has more than one record relating to the main table *entry* only the last record in the XML will be imported to MS Access. I am using the code above for importing all Elements.

[edit]
I have now managed to resolve issue 2 by correcting the following piece of code in the XSLT file:

```
    <xsl:template match="Element1">
    <Element2>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Element2>
</xsl:template>
```

Element1 is my reference point that contains multiple child elements in the source XML.

Element2 to /Element2 is the resulting XML code, so in my case the same as Element1, but by choosing different Element1 & Element2 one can modify the structure of the resulting XML.
the directory structure jumps represented by ../../ is the number of steps to select and copy the *vuln:cve-id* from the *entry* record. so depending on how many levels of child elements you have, you may need to use either ../ or ../../ or none.

the code that works for me now pulling out most of the records and child records, at least the ones I am interested in is below. note that it does not pull out all child tables exactly as per the original XML, but it does give me what I need. One of the simplifications I have made is that all child tables are linked to *vuln:cve-id* even though the source XML has child tables within child tables, but I prefer the flatter structure.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:scap-core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2" xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1" xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0" xmlns:cpe-lang="http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/patch_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/nvd-cve-feed_2.0.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/scap-core_0.1.xsd" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </dataroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cpe-lang:logical-test">
    <cpe-lang:logical-test>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </cpe-lang:logical-test>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:vulnerable-configuration">
    <vuln:vulnerable-configuration>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:vulnerable-configuration>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cpe-lang:logical-test">
    <cpe-lang:logical-test>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <cpe-lang:logical-test><xsl:value-of select="../cpe-lang:logical-test"/></cpe-lang:logical-test>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </cpe-lang:logical-test>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cpe-lang:fact-ref">
    <cpe-lang:fact-ref>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <cpe-lang:fact-ref><xsl:value-of select="../cpe-lang:fact-ref"/></cpe-lang:fact-ref>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </cpe-lang:fact-ref>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="vuln:vulnerable-software-list">
    <vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:product">
    <vuln:product>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <vuln:product><xsl:value-of select="."/></vuln:product>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:product>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cvss:base_metrics">
    <cvss:base_metrics>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </cvss:base_metrics>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:references">
    <vuln:references>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:references>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:scanner">
    <vuln:scanner>
        <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </vuln:scanner>
</xsl:template>
```

note that for the product element, the "." is required to identify the current node, in the line

this is required because of the structure of the original XML, it is different to the rest of the child nodes.

So now it is only issue 1 that is still a problem for me

[end edit]

The plan is that once I get both sets of code working separately I would combine them so that I can import both Attributes and Elements to MS Access.

Very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of actual XML? Your links points to many other links but no one file.

Comment: Hi @Parfait, thanks for looking at this, I updated my original post with an abridged version of the XML that is still representative of what I need to do. I actually figured out my issue 2, so I included this in my updated post as well with some explanations on how to. Grateful for any assistance, Ove.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I have now found the answer to my own question.

The NVD XML is challenging to translate as elements and attributes are nested at different levels in the original XML.

The code I am using to import this now is as follows

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:scap-core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2" xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1" xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0" xmlns:cpe-lang="http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/patch_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/nvd-cve-feed_2.0.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/scap-core_0.1.xsd" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<!--     create a copy of original XML    -->


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<!--     Create "vulnerable-configuration-att" Table        -->
<!--     Add "cve-id" to "vulnerable-configuration" Table   -->
<!--     adding "id" atribute to element                    -->
<!--     adding "operator" atribute to element              -->
<!--     adding "negate" atribute to element                -->


    <xsl:template match="@*|vuln:vulnerable-configuration">
        <vulnerable-configuration-att>
            <vuln:cve-id> <xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/> </vuln:cve-id>
            <cve-sub-id> <xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/> </cve-sub-id>
            <xsl:element name="config-id"> <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="operator"> <xsl:value-of select="//@operator"/> </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="negate"> <xsl:value-of select="//@negate"/> </xsl:element>
        </vulnerable-configuration-att>
    </xsl:template>




<!--     Create "cwe-att" Table            -->
<!--     Add "cve-id" to "cwe-att" Table   -->
<!--     adding "id" atribute to element   -->

    <xsl:template match="@*|vuln:cwe">
        <cwe-att>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <vuln:cve-id> <xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/> </vuln:cve-id>
            <vuln:cve-sub-id> <xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/> </vuln:cve-sub-id>
            <xsl:element name="cwe-id"> <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> </xsl:element>
        </cwe-att>
    </xsl:template>





<!--     Create "vuln:definition-att" Table"              -->
<!--     Add "cve-id" to "vuln:definition" Table"         -->
<!--     adding "system" and "href" atribute to element   -->

    <xsl:template match="@*|vuln:definition">
        <definition-att>
            <vuln:cve-id> <xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/> </vuln:cve-id>
            <vuln:cve-sub-id> <xsl:value-of select="../../../vuln:cve-id"/> </vuln:cve-sub-id>
            <xsl:element name="system"> <xsl:value-of select="@system"/> </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="href"> <xsl:value-of select="@href"/> </xsl:element>
        </definition-att>
    </xsl:template>


<!--     Add "cve-id" to "base_metric" Table"   -->

    <xsl:template match="cvss:base_metrics">
        <cvss:base_metrics>
            <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </cvss:base_metrics>
    </xsl:template>


<!--     Add "cve-id" to "vuln:references" Table" as well as attributes  -->
<!--     adding "reference" to be able to link "reference" Table and "references" Table   -->

    <xsl:template match="vuln:references">
        <vuln:references>
            <cve-id> <xsl:value-of select="../vuln:cve-id"/> </cve-id>
            <xsl:element name="xml_lang"> <xsl:value-of select="@xml:lang"/> </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="reference_type"> <xsl:value-of select="@reference_type"/> </xsl:element>
            <reference><xsl:value-of select="."/></reference>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </vuln:references>
    </xsl:template>


<!--     Create "eference-att" Table"                          -->
<!--     Add "cve-id" to "reference-att" Table"                -->
<!--     adding "xml:lang" ,  and "href" atribute to element   -->
<!--     adding "reference" to be able to link "reference" Table and "references" Table   -->

    <xsl:template match="@*|vuln:reference">
        <reference-att>
            <vuln:cve-id> <xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/> </vuln:cve-id>
            <xsl:element name="xml_lang"> <xsl:value-of select="@xml:lang"/> </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="href"> <xsl:value-of select="@href"/> </xsl:element>
            <reference><xsl:value-of select="."/></reference>
        </reference-att>
    </xsl:template>


<!--     Add "cve-id" to "product" Table"   -->

    <xsl:template match="vuln:product">
        <vuln:product>
            <vuln:cve-id><xsl:value-of select="../../vuln:cve-id"/></vuln:cve-id>
            <vuln:product><xsl:value-of select="."/></vuln:product>
        </vuln:product>
    </xsl:template>




</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the challenge with importing atributes at different levels is that you need to select a reference point with "xsl:template match" command and you can only reference each part of the original XML once, hence if you want to import all atributes in the NVD XML you need to use multiple XSLT files and import different levels in stages to MS Access.
below is an example of importing a child table

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:scap-core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2" xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1" xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0" xmlns:cpe-lang="http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/patch_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/nvd-cve-feed_2.0.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/scap-core_0.1.xsd" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<!--     create a copy of original XML    -->


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!--     Create "fact-ref-att" Table                        -->
<!--     Add "cve-id" to "fact-ref-att" Table               -->
<!--     adding "name" atribute to element                  -->

    <xsl:template match="@*|cpe-lang:fact-ref">
            <fact-ref-att>
                <vuln:cve-id> <xsl:value-of select="../../../vuln:cve-id"/> </vuln:cve-id>
                <xsl:element name="fact-ref-name"> <xsl:value-of select="//@name"/> </xsl:element>
            </fact-ref-att>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

By running a second import to Access it is now possible to create a separate table with the fact ref and have that linked to the cve-id. once in Access the two tables can be linked using cve-id.
For each set of attributes that are related children/parents that you want to import you need a separate XSLT file, but if they are both children to the same or different parents, then they can be included in the same XSLT file. the problem only occurs when you try to convert a child nested in a parent.

Comment: One important bit to add here.  If you import each XML file individually (and most likely you will), you must REMOVE the translation file and Re-Add it to the import for each file.  Even though the translation file appears there and seems like it will be applied to your current import, it won't be and you won't see foreign keys for those imported rows.