# Using XSLT to modify XML data on import to Access

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, import

Ok so I'm not very familiar with XML or XSLT and I need to make an XML document import correctly into Access. Ideally I would like the name of the primary element (node?) I'm not great with terminology, to become the value of the DATE element.

I also want everything to display in one table in access. There are currently a few problems like because Board_NUMBER only appears for every 3(could be more with other XML files imported and modified using this XSLT) TRAVELLER_LINES it only displays 9 board results rather than all of the played games. (this is for a database of bridge results) I also would possibly like to delete all other elements from the EVENTS.

So the XML(s) that will be modified is (bridge results imput in USEBIO format):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE USEBIO SYSTEM "http://www.ebu.co.uk/usebio/usebio_v1_0.dtd">
<USEBIO Version="1.1">
<CLUB>
<CLUB_NAME>*****@hotmail.com</CLUB_NAME>
<CLUB_ID_NUMBER>9999</CLUB_ID_NUMBER>
</CLUB>
<EVENT EVENT_TYPE="MP_PAIRS">
<EVENT_IDENTIFIER>13</EVENT_IDENTIFIER>
<EVENT_DESCRIPTION>Thursday - Section A</EVENT_DESCRIPTION>
<PROGRAM_NAME>Compscore2</PROGRAM_NAME>
<TITLE>Thursday</TITLE>
<DATE>19/05/2016</DATE>
<VENUE></VENUE> 
<P2P_CHARGE_RATE>10</P2P_CHARGE_RATE>
<MPS_AWARDED_FLAG>Y</MPS_AWARDED_FLAG>
<PARTICIPANTS EVENT_TYPE="MP_PAIRS">
 <PAIR>
  <PAIR_NUMBER>1NS</PAIR_NUMBER>
  <DIRECTION>NS</DIRECTION>
  <TOTAL_SCORE>18.00</TOTAL_SCORE>
  <PERCENTAGE>50.00</PERCENTAGE>
  <PLACE>2</PLACE>
  <MASTER_POINTS_AWARDED>6</MASTER_POINTS_AWARDED>
  <PLAYER>
   <PLAYER_NAME>TEST</PLAYER_NAME>
   <NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER></NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER>
   <CLUB_ID_NUMBER>1</CLUB_ID_NUMBER>
  </PLAYER>
  <PLAYER>
   <PLAYER_NAME>TEST2</PLAYER_NAME>
   <NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER></NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER>
   <CLUB_ID_NUMBER>2</CLUB_ID_NUMBER>
  </PLAYER>
 </PAIR>
 <PAIR>
  <PAIR_NUMBER>1EW</PAIR_NUMBER>
  <DIRECTION>EW</DIRECTION>
  <TOTAL_SCORE>21.00</TOTAL_SCORE>
  <PERCENTAGE>58.33</PERCENTAGE>
  <PLACE>1</PLACE>
  <MASTER_POINTS_AWARDED>9</MASTER_POINTS_AWARDED>
  <PLAYER>
   <PLAYER_NAME>TEST 3</PLAYER_NAME>
   <NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER></NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER>
   <CLUB_ID_NUMBER>3</CLUB_ID_NUMBER>
 </PLAYER>
 ...
</PARTICIPANTS>
<BOARD EVENT_TYPE="MP_PAIRS">
  <BOARD_NUMBER>1</BOARD_NUMBER>
  <TRAVELLER_LINE>
  <NS_PAIR_NUMBER>1NS</NS_PAIR_NUMBER>
  <EW_PAIR_NUMBER>1EW</EW_PAIR_NUMBER>
  <CONTRACT>2NT</CONTRACT>
  <PLAYED_BY>N</PLAYED_BY>
  <LEAD>5H</LEAD>
  <TRICKS>9</TRICKS>
  <SCORE>150</SCORE>
  <NS_MATCH_POINTS>0</NS_MATCH_POINTS>
  <EW_MATCH_POINTS>4</EW_MATCH_POINTS>
 </TRAVELLER_LINE>
 <TRAVELLER_LINE>
  <NS_PAIR_NUMBER>2NS</NS_PAIR_NUMBER>
  <EW_PAIR_NUMBER>2EW</EW_PAIR_NUMBER>
  <CONTRACT>3NT</CONTRACT>
  <PLAYED_BY>N</PLAYED_BY>
  <LEAD>4H</LEAD>
  <TRICKS>10</TRICKS>
  <SCORE>430</SCORE>
  <NS_MATCH_POINTS>4</NS_MATCH_POINTS>
  <EW_MATCH_POINTS>0</EW_MATCH_POINTS>
 </TRAVELLER_LINE>
 <TRAVELLER_LINE>
  <NS_PAIR_NUMBER>3NS</NS_PAIR_NUMBER>
  <EW_PAIR_NUMBER>3EW</EW_PAIR_NUMBER>
  <CONTRACT>3NT</CONTRACT>
  <PLAYED_BY>N</PLAYED_BY>
  <LEAD>4H</LEAD>
  <TRICKS>9</TRICKS>
  <SCORE>400</SCORE>
  <NS_MATCH_POINTS>2</NS_MATCH_POINTS>
  <EW_MATCH_POINTS>2</EW_MATCH_POINTS>
 </TRAVELLER_LINE>
</BOARD>
 <BOARD EVENT_TYPE="MP_PAIRS">
  <BOARD_NUMBER>2</BOARD_NUMBER>
  <TRAVELLER_LINE>
   <NS_PAIR_NUMBER>1NS</NS_PAIR_NUMBER>
   <EW_PAIR_NUMBER>1EW</EW_PAIR_NUMBER>
   <CONTRACT>1NT</CONTRACT>
   <PLAYED_BY>N</PLAYED_BY>
   <LEAD>3S</LEAD>
   <TRICKS>7</TRICKS>
   <SCORE>90</SCORE>
   <NS_MATCH_POINTS>3</NS_MATCH_POINTS>
   <EW_MATCH_POINTS>1</EW_MATCH_POINTS>
  </TRAVELLER_LINE>
...
</EVENT>
</USEBIO>
```

I'm not sure at all what the outcome should look like as I don't know how well it will import into Access but the fields like

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE USEBIO SYSTEM "http://www.ebu.co.uk/usebio/usebio_v1_0.dtd">
<USEBIO Version="1.1">
 <19/05/2016>
   <EVENT_DESCRIPTION>Thursday - Section A</EVENT_DESCRIPTION>
   <DATE>19/05/2016</DATE>
   <PAIR_NUMBER>1NS</PAIR_NUMBER>
   <DIRECTION>NS</DIRECTION>
   <TOTAL_SCORE>18.00</TOTAL_SCORE>
   <PERCENTAGE>50.00</PERCENTAGE>
   <PLACE>2</PLACE>
   <MASTER_POINTS_AWARDED>6</MASTER_POINTS_AWARDED>
   <PLAYER_NAME>TEST</PLAYER_NAME>
   <NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER></NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER>
   <CLUB_ID_NUMBER>1</CLUB_ID_NUMBER>
   <PAIR_NUMBER>1NS</PAIR_NUMBER>
   <PLAYER_NAME>TEST2</PLAYER_NAME>
   <NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER></NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER>
   <CLUB_ID_NUMBER>2</CLUB_ID_NUMBER>
   <PAIR_NUMBER>1EW</PAIR_NUMBER>
   <DIRECTION>EW</DIRECTION>
   <TOTAL_SCORE>21.00</TOTAL_SCORE>
   <PERCENTAGE>58.33</PERCENTAGE>
   <PLACE>1</PLACE>
   <MASTER_POINTS_AWARDED>9</MASTER_POINTS_AWARDED>
   <PLAYER_NAME>TEST 3</PLAYER_NAME>
   <NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER></NATIONAL_ID_NUMBER>
   <CLUB_ID_NUMBER>3</CLUB_ID_NUMBER>
 ...
   <BOARD_NUMBER>1</BOARD_NUMBER>
   <NS_PAIR_NUMBER>1NS</NS_PAIR_NUMBER>
   <EW_PAIR_NUMBER>1EW</EW_PAIR_NUMBER>
   <CONTRACT>2NT</CONTRACT>
   <PLAYED_BY>N</PLAYED_BY>
   <LEAD>5H</LEAD>
   <TRICKS>9</TRICKS>
   <SCORE>150</SCORE>
   <NS_MATCH_POINTS>0</NS_MATCH_POINTS>
   <EW_MATCH_POINTS>4</EW_MATCH_POINTS>
   <BOARD_NUMBER>1</BOARD_NUMBER>
   <NS_PAIR_NUMBER>2NS</NS_PAIR_NUMBER>
   <EW_PAIR_NUMBER>2EW</EW_PAIR_NUMBER>
   <CONTRACT>3NT</CONTRACT>
   <PLAYED_BY>N</PLAYED_BY>
   <LEAD>4H</LEAD>
   <TRICKS>10</TRICKS>
   <SCORE>430</SCORE>
   <NS_MATCH_POINTS>4</NS_MATCH_POINTS>
   <EW_MATCH_POINTS>0</EW_MATCH_POINTS>
   <BOARD_NUMBER>1</BOARD_NUMBER>
   <NS_PAIR_NUMBER>3NS</NS_PAIR_NUMBER>
   <EW_PAIR_NUMBER>3EW</EW_PAIR_NUMBER>
   <CONTRACT>3NT</CONTRACT>
   <PLAYED_BY>N</PLAYED_BY>
   <LEAD>4H</LEAD>
   <TRICKS>9</TRICKS>
   <SCORE>400</SCORE>
   <NS_MATCH_POINTS>2</NS_MATCH_POINTS>
   <EW_MATCH_POINTS>2</EW_MATCH_POINTS>
   <BOARD_NUMBER>2</BOARD_NUMBER>
   <NS_PAIR_NUMBER>1NS</NS_PAIR_NUMBER>
   <EW_PAIR_NUMBER>1EW</EW_PAIR_NUMBER>
   <CONTRACT>1NT</CONTRACT>
   <PLAYED_BY>N</PLAYED_BY>
   <LEAD>3S</LEAD>
   <TRICKS>7</TRICKS>
   <SCORE>90</SCORE>
   <NS_MATCH_POINTS>3</NS_MATCH_POINTS>
   <EW_MATCH_POINTS>1</EW_MATCH_POINTS>
    ...
 </19/05/2016>
</USEBIO>
```

Comment: Did you mean MS Access of the Microsoft Office Suite? Please tag appropriately: `ms-access` and mention in post as *access* is a common English word.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30037963/2144390) help?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you are new to XML, I can highly advice you [the XML tutorial from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp). The name of your element cannot be a date like `<19/05/2016>` because the format is not valid. See in the linked page:

> XML elements must follow these naming rules:
>
> - Element names are case-sensitive
> - Element names must start with a letter or underscore
> - Element names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
> - Element names can contain letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, and periods
> - Element names cannot contain spaces
>
> Any name can be used, no words are reserved (except xml).

but your element could have an attribute with the date as value.