# Importing xml file into Access database with defined id

Tags: python, sql, xml

I am strugling in order to import an enormous amount of data from xml file into Access.
The problem I am facing is that files I want to import does contain the first row with id

```
<vin id="11111111111111111">
<description>Mazda3 L 2.0l MZR 150 PS 4T 5AG AL-EDITION TRA-P</description>
<type>BL</type>
<typeapproval>e11*2001/116*0262*07</typeapproval>
<variant>B2F</variant>
<version>7EU</version>
<series>Mazda3</series>
<body>L</body>
<engine>2.0l MZR 150 PS</engine>
<grade>AL-EDITION</grade>
<transmission>5AG</transmission>
<colourtype>Mica</colourtype>
<extcolourcode>34K</extcolourcode>
<extcolourcodedescription>Crystal White Pearl</extcolourcodedescription>
<intcolourcode>BU4</intcolourcode>
<intcolourcodedescription>Black</intcolourcodedescription>
<registrationdate>2012-07-20</registrationdate>
<productiondate>2011-11-30</productiondate>
</vin>
```

so the result of my import is all the lines except from the VIN number of vehicle that is actually defined as id.

I was trying to manually replace characters like:

"> etc. with 
etc.

to get rid of that id but I have actually dozens of files and hundreds of thousands records in each file so it is quite a pain...

so I thought about concatinating all files together with a script in python:

```
import os 
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ver='2011'

dirName =r'C:\Users\dawid\Desktop\DE_DATA\Mazda_DE\VINs_DE\Mazda\xml'.format(ver);

out_file=r'C:\Users\dawid\Desktop\DE_DATA\Mazda_DE\VINs_DE\Mazda\Output.xml'.format(ver);


def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    # create a list of file and sub directories 
    # names in the given directory
  
            listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
            allFiles = list()
    # Iterate over all the entries
            for entry in listOfFile:
        # Create full path
               
                fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        # If entry is a directory then get the list of files in this directory 
                if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
                    allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
                else:
                    allFiles.append(fullPath)
                if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
                    allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
                
            return allFiles

listOfFileOut=getListOfFiles(dirName)

#filenames = allFiles
with open(out_file, 'w',encoding='ANSI') as outfile:
    for fname in listOfFileOut:
        with open(fname,encoding='ANSI') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
                
print("Done")
```

But this completely destroyed structure of the xml file and I cannot import it anymore.
Could anyone suggest if it's possilble to use python to get rid of all those ids to be able to import the whole Database in access?

Thank you in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N90Yc.jpg)

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/q/30029303/18157?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import utils, SimplifiedDoc, req

dirName = r'C:\Users\dawid\Desktop\DE_DATA\Mazda_DE\VINs_DE\Mazda\xml'
listFile = utils.getSubFile(dirName, end='.xml')
for f in listFile:
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(utils.getFileContent(f, encoding='ANSI'))
    doc.replaceReg('<vin[^>]*>', '<vin>')
    print(doc.html)
    # utils.saveFile(f, doc.html, encoding='ANSI') # write to original file
```

Result:

```
<vin>
<description>Mazda3 L 2.0l MZR 150 PS 4T 5AG AL-EDITION TRA-P</description>
<type>BL</type>
<typeapproval>e11*2001/116*0262*07</typeapproval>
<variant>B2F</variant>
<version>7EU</version>
...
```